# CPU usage and frequency as a tray icon

Tags: software-rec, cpu-usage

I'd like to display a CPU usage / frequency graph like the Resource Monitor does:

> [image]

in a tray icon like Process Explorer does:

> [image]

In particular, I'd like to see that blue line indicating the actual current CPU frequency as a percentage of the maximum frequency (due to throttling for power usage / noise concerns).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

[Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/RainCMS/) is a good tool that lets you personalize your desktop and has features to allow you to display the CPU usage amoung other things. That may do what you are looking for. I don't think it adds a tray icon, but it is powerful enough to get close.